# How to integrate Angular 4 components with vaadin UI?

Tags: java, angular, vaadin7

I want to use Angular 4 with a Vaadin 7 Java application in order to push a considerable amount of UI logic to client-side, reduce server round trips, make the client-side functionality available during slow network connections, and make use of the best features of both frameworks. I went through the Vaangular project mentioned on Vaadin and AngularJS - happy together article, but it won't work for my requirement since I use Angular 4.

Answer (score 0):

Java has nothing to do with Angular, what Vaadin offers for JavaScript are web components built using Polymer 2, which you need to install using bower, integrate them in your index.html file and use the Angular library vaadin provides. It’s all explained on their Web Components page, where there are instructions for Angular.
This is their official starter which you can recreate (“Recreating this project”) if you have an existing app.
https://github.com/vaadin/base-starter-angular/blob/master/README.md